# Linux error for synergy

Tags: linux, debugging, curl, installation

I was installing synergy in my linux machine . i downloaded the tar.gz version and extracted it. after moving into the folder when i executed the command ./configure 
I got this error.

--Could NOT find CURL (missing : CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt :161 (message):
Missing library: curl

--configuring incomplete , errors occurred!

can anybody please help me in debugging
thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't mention the distro but you may have to install the libcurl package.

Comment: I tried installing libcurl but i got error Unable to locate package libcurl. and its ubuntu 12.04

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu I believe the package is called `libcurl4-openssl-dev` . To install it you will have to use `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` .

Answer (score 1):

Check the compile page on Synergy wiki.

https://github.com/synergy/synergy/wiki/Compiling#Ubuntu_1004_to_1504

Comment: This link has moved as symless has moved their repository to GitHub.

https://github.com/symless/synergy/wiki/Compiling